# Database Schema for Student Report

Tags: database, schema

I am trying to create a database schema for creating an online grade report.  The report contains the name of the school, the name of the student, the name of the student’s teacher, the number of absent days, the number of tardy days, the student’s current overall grade, and the name of all assignments completed by the student including the date, category, and score for each of those assignments.  The following is what I’ve been able to figure out so far.  Does anyone have any suggestions about improving this schema?

```
School (school_id, school_name, course_id)

Course(course_id, course_name, teacher_id, student_id)

Teacher(teacher_id, teacher_name, student_id)

Student(student_id, student_name, grade, absent_days, tardy_days, assignment_id)

Assignment(assignment_id, assignment_name, assignment_date, category, score, course_id)
```

Comment: Can a teacher teach in several schools?

Comment: You should read a book or tutorial about Relational DBs. Because clearly you don't even know the concept of Foreign Keys.

In your schema a teacher is assigned to a one teacher, a school has only one course, a student can only have one assignment, ...

Comment: James Bond...this database will only contain data for one school.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the course_id from the school. The student_id from the course & teacher. The assignment_id from the student as described below. In addition I would probably split the assignments into an Assignment and a Mark table.

This results in the schema that a school can have multiple teachers that teach multiple classes that can have multiple assignments. The students belong to a school and can have multiple assignments. This is a pretty simple model and you might consider adding a 'Booking' table in which you store what students have booked what courses. In addition it might be possible that multiple teachers teach a course and teachers work in multiple schools or a course is offered in multiple schools. Just some ideas to think about...

```
School (school_id, school_name)

Course(course_id, course_name, teacher_id)

Teacher(teacher_id, teacher_name, school_id)

Student(student_id, student_name, absent_days, tardy_days, school_id)

Assignment(assignment_id, assignment_name, assignment_date, category, score, course_id, student_id)
```

Comment: I just want to make sure that I understand.  By "booking table" do you mean a class roster that lists the students for each class?  So for example something like the following: Roster(course_id, student_id)

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean.

Comment: One more question.  What is the purpose/logic of removing the student_id from the course and teacher?

Comment: I assume a course like 'French level 1' does exist only once in the database and it can have several students. Same goes for a teacher: 'Prof X' exists only once in the database and can have several students. As @Salih Erikci said above in the comments, you should really spend some time on reading up on relational database modeling.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a sample school database for free. If you find that is helpful:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/resources/school-database
```